# What are the differences between private jre and public jre?

Tags: java

What are the differences between private jre and public jre?
Is there some official paper about this topic?

I didn't find any question on SO about this topic. Nor I was able to find something fulfilling around.

Comment: May this helps : http://blog.sarathonline.com/2008/07/public-and-private-jre.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> A JRE is nothing but a folder that contains JVM executables, setting
>   files, required lib files, and extensions. You can install multiple
>   JREs on your system Sun generally installs versions in C:\Program
>   Files\Java as jre eg.jre1.6.0_06.
>
> A Public JRE is available to all Java programs, Browsers, and the libs
>   in this JRE folder are available to applications started in command
>   line like java com.sarathonline.cli.HelloWorld This JRE is also
>   registered in path, and Browser plugin.
>
> A Private JRE is something that is installed in the system but is not
>   referred to by default. This could be a copy of the JRE / JDK folder
>   from another installed directory. If you see a my earlier post: 
>   starting eclipse with jre 1.6 where your environment is in 1.4, The
>   JRE1.6 is used only by Eclipse, this is a private JRE. While the
>   JAVA_HOME points to 1.4. This is a public JRE.

Source:

http://blog.sarathonline.com/2008/07/public-and-private-jre.html

Some more discussion on the topic:

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t649860-private-vs-public-jre-in-different-oss.html

Comment: Here is the official reference you asked for:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#private

Copy of the most important parts (as of Jun 2016) in the following comment:

Comment: "The private JRE [...] is contained entirely in a jre directory (typically at C:\Program Files\jdk1.7.0\jre) whose location is known only to the JDK. [...] the public JRE can be used by other Java applications, is contained outside the JDK (typically at C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.7.0), is registered with the Windows registry (at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft), can be removed using Add/Remove Programs, might be registered with browsers, and might have the java.exe file copied to the Windows system directory (which would make it the default system Java platform)."

Comment: The quote is misleading though - a private JRE doesn't have to be inside a JDK. Any JRE that's not configured as the operating system default is a private JRE.

Answer (score 5):

The official answer, [from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html#CHDJCCEG):

> ### Private Versus Public JRE
>
> Installing the JDK also installs a private JRE and optionally a public
>   copy. The private JRE is required to run the tools included with the
>   JDK. It has no registry settings and is contained entirely in a jre
>   directory (typically at C:\Program Files\jdk1.8.0\jre) whose location
>   is known only to the JDK. On the other hand, the public JRE can be
>   used by other Java applications, is contained outside the JDK
>   (typically at C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0), is registered with the
>   Windows registry (at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft), can be
>   removed using Add/Remove Programs, might be registered with browsers,
>   and might have the java.exe file copied to the Windows system
>   directory (which would make it the default system Java platform).

Comment: Unfortunately, JDK installation program does not let you to NOT install its private JRE, it only allows you to NOT install the public one. Which btw. eats as much as 110MB on your hard drive (v9), which is not a little piece of cake in the age of SSD drives. What a BAAAAD design of Oracle! Why do you have to install TWO pieces of 110MB elephant, IF THEY ARE THE SAME? Disappointing!

Comment: @Palo Maybe you can delete the private JRE and instead create a symlink that points to the public JRE. This, of course assumes that the public JRE can replace the private JRE for the software included in the JDK.

Comment: Install a public JRE trust me, beside the symlinks and regedit, there is so much going on, that using the private JRE cost me so much time, because it was not "really" installed. VERY bad design choice.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very simple: the public JRE is the one users will use if they want to run anything Java. The private JRE is a different installation that one can use, if the explicitly execute that Java binary (e.g. on Windows: "C:\Programs\Java\MyJava\bin\java.exe").

Comment: This answer does not point to a difference other than using vague terms "anything Java" vs "explicitly .. that Java".

Answer (score 1):

Private JRE ->Private JRE is Used for compilation of Java Application when both Public and private JRE is available and its installation location is defined by user.

Public JRE -> Public JRE is used for Execution of Java Application when both Public and private JRE is available....if in case Private JRE is not available then both Compilation and Execution process will be done by Public JRE.