# Is just a "javaw.exe" enough to run a simple Java application on a Windows machine without JRE installed?

Tags: java

I guess, the title is self-descriptive. I'll just add my imports if that matters:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

So will just a single javaw executable be enough to run this app on a Windows machine if it has no JRE installed?

Comment: No it's not, you would at least miss required native libraries (.dll / .so)

Comment: @Aaron And JARs ofc.

Comment: Okay guys, thanks! It was easier to ask a question here than to uninstall JRE on my computer and try it myself ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java runtime is more than just an executable binary.

It contains all the compiled classes that your import statements make use of. And various other binaries (such as DLLs}, too.

So the simple answer is: no.

Java9 is about to introduce new tooling that would allow you to create a binary artifact that only contains those classes that are required by your application. Or to be precise: those modules that your application needs. 
But that still means that you have to do something to make use of this.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thanks!

Comment: @GhostCat If the new tooling that you pointed is to make use of application class data sharing then it would be Java10 or above.

Comment: I think it is called jlink. And it relies on module definitions.

Comment: From what I understand, jlink is practically a way to make your own custom JRE much smaller by picking only the modules you want (now that it is moduler and modules have dependencies). Problem with custom JREs (in general I guess, not just ones assembled using jlink) is that you have to update them yourself, as mentioned at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an installed JRE, you can ship a private one inside your application (without installing the JRE on the client machine). But javaw.exe isn't enough. See [What are the differences between private jre and public jre?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510169/what-are-the-differences-between-private-jre-and-public-jre)

Also, there are installers that can pack both your app and a JRE in an executable and make it appear as if it is a single running file (without unpacking it - they map file system calls inside the file I think). If I remember well InstallAnywhere could do that, but probably there are other installers too that can.

Comment: Thanks, man. I already found out about Launch4j and it worked like charm.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/ - hadn't caught up with that one. Seems it can be used on any platform to build Windows executables that can target specific JREs or bundle them. Guess those will be quite big EXEs, but with the jlink tool mentioned at other comment (to keep only the Java VM modules you need), it does have potential

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to have JRE installed as well as you can configure system variable PATH, but this is optional but increase convenience.

Comment: You don't *need* to configure PATH, it's just more convenient.